# Using Knoll Light Factory and AE's Fractal Noise to improve volumetric lighting in Trapcode Lux

Tags: after-effects, plugins

What are the steps necessary to create this?

https://twitter.com/RedGiantNews/status/1425145716675125251

Specifically how do you use the built in fractal noise plugin to create what looks like volumetric smoke effects in Lux? (And how do you get the text to appear as a black shadow before the third light comes on).